# vccw+wordmoveでssh接続した場合のデータベースのpullについて

Tags: wordpress

初投稿です。
タイトルの通り、wordmoveを用いてリモートのwordpressからデータをpullしてきた際にエラーなどは発生しないのですが、データベースのみ引き継げなくて困っております。
pullしてくる際に、エラーがでないので何が原因かわからず困っております。
このような現象の対応法をご存知でしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

adapt dumpが実行されているのに、データベースが一切反映されていない事と、ワードプレスの設定画面が出ること、excludeでwp-config.phpが除外されている点からwp-config.phpをローカルの設定+プリフィックスを合わせて設置してから、wordmove pull -allしたところ反映されました。 
質問を御覧頂いた皆様ありがとうございます。